# Laravel Nesting to 4 levels not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have relationships like the following:

Category -> Subcategory -> Product -> Price

A Category contains X Subcategories.
A Subcategory contains X Products.
A Product contains X Prices (New Price, Old Price, One Record per Price Change)

I wanted to do the following:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    [...]
    @foreach($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
        [...]
        @foreach($subcategory->products as $product)
            [...]
                @foreach($product->prices as $price)


[... @endforeach x4 ...]
```

The 3 first levels are working. When using the 4th however ($product->prices) I get an `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

The relationships in the Models:

**Category.php**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategory');
    }
}
```

**SubCategory.php**

```
class SubCategory extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

**Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SubCategory');
    }

    public function price()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductPrice');
    }
}
```

**ProductPrice.php**

```
class ProductPrice extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

This is what I send to my View:

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function showMainPage()
    {
        $categories = Category::with('subcategories')->get();

        $data = array(
          "categories" => $categories,
        );

        return view('index')->with($data);
    }
}
```

This worked fine, even with Products but began to have errors when using the ProductPrices.

Comment: `$categories = Category::with('subcategories.products.prices')->get();`

Comment: exactly the same error @GONG

Comment: You trying to call `$product->prices` while your relation is `price`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GONG said, change your code for use eager load, this will run so much faster than use some foreaches.

See laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: I am eager loading, or am I wrong? But I need to foreach them because I want to load ALL records from the DB and show them. For exampe I am in fact using $category->subcategories->products to load all products from a subcategory. Can you explain If I did something wrong?